# Dropdown menu where each item changes the image above

Tags: javascript, html, image, dropdown

I am aiming to create a dropdown menu that when each item of the dropdown is clicked, it shows a different image above it, by replacing the one before. I have been using these pages as guidance:

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869401/display-an-image-only-when-button-is-clicked)

[W3Schools Dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp)

The dropdown menu has nine options and the html looks like this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<img id="a_features" src="a_features" style="display:none;"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Change in Audio Features Over Time</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <a onclick="danceability()">Danceability</a>
  <a onclick="duration()">Duration</a>
  <a onclick="energy()">Energy</a>
  <a onclick="instrumentalness()">Instrumentalness</a>
  <a onclick="liveness()">Liveness</a>
  <a onclick="loudness()">Loudness</a>
  <a onclick="speechiness()">Speechiness</a>
  <a onclick="tempo()">Tempo</a>
  <a onclick="valence()">Valence</a>
</div>
```

And one example of the functions I am using, they are all identical except for the image source, is this:

```
function danceability(){
    var pic = "https://imgur.com/Ga5bnai"
    document.getElementById('a_features').src = pic.replace('90x90', '225x225');
    document.getElementById('a_features').style.display='block';
}
```

This setup works when I use the image used in the stack overflow example ("http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/118/5000175411118/IDShot_90x90.jpg"), but fails when I try and link it to the images hosted on imgur. Is this an issue with the image source and, if so, how do I get around this?

Comment: Your text for `pic` doesn't have the string `90x90` in it, so nothing happens.

Comment: Where would I put the string?

Comment: If you look at the SO image URL carefully, it is `var pic = "http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/118/5000175411118/IDShot_90x90.jpg"`, (note the `90x90` at the end) and there is a (hidden) image `var pic = "http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/118/5000175411118/IDShot_225x225.jpg` for the new size. You will need to supply **both** images.

Comment: Thank you, how do I provide the hidden one?

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems like the imgur link you're using (if it's the one you're actually using), (a) doesn't link to an image but to a webpage (b) does not include '90x90', so won't replace it with anything else.
If you would replace the src with a link to an actual image it would probably work.
Also, you can generalize the function. Instead of calling a different function on each item, you could call 1 function, and add the image src in a data-attribute, for instance:

```html
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <a data-image="https://imgur.com/Ga5bnai">Danceability</a>
  <a data-image="https://imgur.com/35ewr">Duration</a>
  <a data-image="https://imgur.com/fas353F">Energy</a>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

```js
const image = document.getElementById('a_features');

const setImage = (element) => {
  const src = element.dataset.image;
  image.src = src.replace('90x90', '225x225');
  image.style.display = 'block';
}

document.querySelectorAll('#myDropdown a').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => setImage(item));
});
```

An example: https://codepen.io/dagropp/pen/WNZzaay

Comment: In your example why leaving the `image.src = src.replace('90x90', '225x225');` line ?

Comment: When I use the direct link, it still doesn't seem to work, does that mean https://i.imgur.com/x9BkKGy.jpg is to a webpage and not an image? Where should I include the 90x90 so that it knows what to replace? Thank you for comments on generalisation, that is really useful.

Comment: Check this pen: https://codepen.io/dagropp/pen/WNZzaay

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this. It works for me in codepen, but when I bring it down to my editor it doesn't work. The console gives a 403 whenever i click on the options, I will have another play with it.